# Permission denied error when a batch of users are subscribed to a topic in Firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

We're migrating our customers from GCM to Firebase for Android push notifications. Because of this, we need to import the topics our users subscribed to into Firebase. We have a Java backend and we're using the firebase admin library. We are calling FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic for that.

It worked fine for most of our smaller customers. However, it fails for our bigger ones. We get a "permission denied" error. Unfortunately this error is not documented (and actually unsupported by the library which turns it into an "unknown error"), so I'm not too sure what to do. Could it be that we have to pay something when larger amounts of topic subscriptions are imported?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/55605710/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your advice. However, I can't give code to reproduce this because I would have to give customer secrets (as the code works for some customers but not others). Anyway, I'm not asking for a bug fix. I just want to know what is a "permission denied" error when you use FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you will get this error if you use the private key of a wrong firebase project. This is undocumented at the time of writing this answer.